# Get a type as enum values of object and pass the readonly object as props - React Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-typescript

I have the following data:

```
const ActionData = [
  { label: 'Edit', icon: 'pen', key: 'edit' },
  { label: 'Skip', icon: 'forward', key: 'skip' },
  { label: 'Stop', icon: 'stop-circle', key: 'stop' },
];
```

which I use to display list of Actions

```
{ActionData.map((dataItem) => (
        <ActionItem 
          key={dataItem.key}
          item={dataItem} 
          onPress={handleActionClick} 
        />
))}
```

I need a type **ActionItemKeyType** which should be **'edit' | 'skip' | 'stop'**. i.e. keys of ActionData

If I declare ActionData as const

```
const ActionData = [
  { label: 'Edit', icon: 'pen', key: 'edit' },
  { label: 'Skip', icon: 'forward', key: 'skip' },
  { label: 'Stop', icon: 'stop-circle', key: 'stop' },
] as const;
```

then I am able to get the type **ActionItemKeyType** as expected using the following code

```
type ActionItemKeyType = typeof ActionData[number]['key'];
```

But if I declare ActionData in this way, then I can't pass the item props in my render method because the Array is read-only.

How can I achieve both the functionalities?

Comment: Can't you type `ActionData`? Ts think `ActionData` is of type `{key: string, icon: string, label: string}[]`, for this `ActionItemKeyType` is `string` and not `"edit" | "skip" | "stop"`

Comment: @Nullndr By type **ActionData** do u mean this

`type ActionItemKeyType = 'edit' | 'skip' | 'stop';`
`type ActionDataType = {label: string; icon: string; key: ActionItemKeyType}[];`

I've currently used this, but this feels as a workaround, because this is not a feasible solution when my data length increases. I'm looking for something which can automatically create a type based on data

Comment: This is the beast approach since ts will not need to infer the type of `ActionData`

Comment: I think you can achieve what you want by typing `item` of the `ActionItem` props to `typeof ActionData[number];`. Like [so](https://t.ly/-P92)

Comment: @Nullndr Thanks, using this approach for now until someone suggests a better one

Comment: @colinD this will give the type as {key: string, icon: string, label: string}

Comment: I'm missing something then, in the example I sent, the type of `item` is `{
    readonly label: "Edit";
    readonly icon: "pen";
    readonly key: "edit";
} | {
    readonly label: "Skip";
    readonly icon: "forward";
    readonly key: "skip";
} | {
    readonly label: "Stop";
    readonly icon: "stop-circle";
    readonly key: "stop";
}`
Isn't it what you want?

Comment: @colinD I think, I was doing some mistake in declaring the types. I am able to achieve it now. Thanks!